# Pandas: Get before and after rows based on 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to use pandas to get the row before and row after any record in the store column that is not null. However, I need to group it based on the Key column so that it doesn't pull in additional records from a non-related Key.

Here is the data:

```
Store     Key       Time
          1-1-ABC   1pm
1         1-1-ABC   2pm
          1-1-ABC   3pm
2         1-2-BCD   1pm
          1-2-BCD   2pm
          1-2-BCD   3pm
          1-1-CDE   1pm
          1-1-CDE   2pm
          1-1-CDE   3pm
3         1-1-CDE   4pm
4         2-1-EFG   1pm
          2-1-EFG   2pm
          2-1-EFG   3pm
5         1-3-LMN   1pm
          1-3-LMN   2pm
          1-3-LMN   3pm
```

The results should look like this:

```
Store     Key       Time
          1-1-ABC   1pm
 1        1-1-ABC   2pm
          1-1-ABC   3pm
 2        1-2-BCD   1pm
          1-2-BCD   2pm
          1-1-CDE   3pm
 3        1-1-CDE   4pm
 4        2-1-EFG   1pm
          2-1-EFG   2pm
 5        1-3-LMN   1pm
          1-3-LMN   2pm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using numpy `clip` +`concatenate`

```
l=[]
for _,df1 in df.groupby('Key'):

    idx=df1.Store.replace('',np.nan).notnull().nonzero()[0]
    l.append(df1.iloc[np.unique(np.clip(np.concatenate(np.array([idx-1,idx,idx+1])),0,len(df1)-1))])


pd.concat(l).sort_index()



Out[196]: 
   Store      Key Time
0         1-1-ABC  1pm
1      1  1-1-ABC  2pm
2         1-1-ABC  3pm
3      2  1-2-BCD  1pm
4         1-2-BCD  2pm
8         1-1-CDE  3pm
9      3  1-1-CDE  4pm
10     4  2-1-EFG  1pm
11        2-1-EFG  2pm
13     5  1-3-LMN  1pm
14        1-3-LMN  2pm
```

Comment: Hi Wen. I updated the sample tables. In your results using the updated table you get     2-1-EFG   3pm    coming through. Since they Key to Store 5 is 1-3-LMN I don't want to bring in 2-1-EFG  3pm.   This is where somehow grouping first and then getting the before and after rows are important which is where I'm having issues.  Thanks.

Comment: @Chan Yw~ :-)  happy coding